# Android - return value from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, gridview

I have a function that retrieve images from the resource and display it in a `GridView`.
Everithing works fine but due to a performance issue I would like to create at runtime thumbs so I create a new `ProgressDialog` to let know the user that the app is working:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.italiandevteam.chuck.adapter.GridViewAdapter;
import com.italiandevteam.chuck.model.ImageItem;

public class GalleriaPersonaggio extends Fragment{

    Integer personaggio = null;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    TypedArray imgs = null;

    final ArrayList imageItems = new ArrayList();

    public GalleriaPersonaggio( int personaggio ){

        this.personaggio = personaggio;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int id = getIdPersonaggio();

        View rootView = null;

        try {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_grid, container, false);
            } 
        catch (InflateException e) {
        }

        final GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.gallery_row, getData(personaggio));
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
//              HashMap<String, Object> hm = gridView.getAdapter().getPosition(position);
//
//                 String imgPath = (String) hm.get("flag"); //get downloaded image path
//              Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MostraImmagine.class); //start new Intent to another Activity.
//              i.putExtra("ClickedImagePath", imgPath ); //put image link in intent.
//              startActivity(i);
            }

    });

        return rootView;
    }

    public int getIdPersonaggio(){
        return this.personaggio;
    }

    private ArrayList getData(int personaggio) {

        // retrieve String drawable array

        switch( personaggio )
        {        
            case 1:{
                imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.chuck_ids);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.sarah_ids);
                break;
            }

            default:{
                imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.chuck_ids);
            }

        }



        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait ...", "Loading Images ...", true);
                ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {

                                int THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT = 100;
                                int THUMBNAIL_WIGHT = 100;
                                for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) 
                                {
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT, THUMBNAIL_WIGHT, false);
//                                  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
//                                  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
//                                  byte[] imageData = baos.toByteArray();
//                                  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
//                                  Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                                    imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }).start();


        return imageItems;

    }
}
```

The problem is that at the end the code doesn't return anything, the `GridView` is empty, if I remove the thread it works well.

Comment: You'll need to create a `Handler` to tell the UI thread to update the GridView once you've retrieved the data. To make it easier, Android provides the `AsyncTask`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: How can I pass my ArrayList to the AsyncTask?

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi i made a quick example of AsyncTask if you still need help.

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi ti sei impiccato (you hanged)? ;-)

Comment: Ho dovuto lasciare un attimo indietro il progetto, appena possibile lo riprendo :)

Answer (score 0):

Thread instances can not return values, since the run method has return type void. What you can do is to to implement the `delegate` pattern (Listener in Android), or switch to the `Callable` interface and `Executors`. Please be aware that waiting for the return type **could** not make sense. If you something:

Pseudo code
UIThread:

```
variable = threadInstance.getResult();
```

you made an asynchronous call, synchronous

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by 323go, you can use **AsyncTask** (much better IMHO). Create an internal class like this:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Integer, Long> {
    ...
}
```

Integer is used to update a progress dialog (if you don't need one, just put Void instead); Long is the result of *DoInBackground* method. Launch your AsyncTask like this:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute(passing);
```

Now i don't know what you are aiming, but if you follow the link suggested by 323go or [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask), you can improve your code.

**EDIT**

After 323go comments, it is better to pass your ArrayList of object in AsyncTask constructor:

```
new MyAsyncTask(passing).execute();
```

Of course in your AsyncTask class you have to create an internal variable:

```
...
private ArrayList<Object> myArrayList;

private MyAsyncTask(ArrayList<Object> anArrayList) {
    myArrayList = anArrayList;
}
...
```

Comment: It'd be better pass the `ArrayList` to the subclassed constructor and have the `doInBackground()` return a fresh `ArrayList` to be assigned in `onPostExecute()`. This avoids concurrency issues, as `doInBackground()` runs on a different threat.